# invoke button on webservice missing

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2017, web-config, iis-6

I've created a web service, using vs 2017, .net 4.61. The web service works like a charm when I browse from the server using iis, but if I test on my local machine, the invoke button disappears.

I've tried adding in the following code, just above the  section in the web.config file -

```
  <webServices>
<protocols>
  <add name="HttpGet"/>
  <add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
```

but I get an error "The configuration section 'webServices' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration".

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The invoke button disappears ... A note, in my job, i don't have a administrator privilege for my local machine and i need open visual studio with administrator privilege to run a wcf service. You try this?

Comment: Thanks @D3ivid. I have admin privileges on my machine, and the server admin  (or others) isn't able to see it either. But we're running it as a website though, not through the VS. .. https://servername/WS is pretty much what we're using.

Answer (score 1):

The following was added after the connectionStrings section -

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" /> 
    <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpSoap12"/>
      <add name="HttpSoap"/>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```